# How to loop from every nth element of an array using a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to loop from every fourth element in the answer array, and my code is not working.

This is the output I need:

```
Question 1
Answer 1
Answer 2
Answer 3
Answer 4
Question2
Answer A
Answer B
Answer C
Answer D
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
Question 1
Answer 1
Answer 2
Answer 3
Answer 4
Question 2
Answer 1
Answer 2
Answer 3
Answer 4
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
String[]question = new String[2];
question[0] = "Question 1"; 
question[2] = "Question 2";      

String[]answer = new String[8];
answer[0] = "Answer 1";
answer[1] = "Answer 2";
answer[2] = "Answer 3";
answer[3] = "Answer 4";
answer[4] = "Answer A";
answer[5] = "Answer B";
answer[6] = "Answer C";
answer[7] = "Answer D";

for (int i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(question[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j<4; j++) {
        System.out.println(answer[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(answer[i*4 + j])`. Also it should be `question[1] = "Question 2";` (array index can't be equal to its size). Overall it is comfortable to define arrays as `String questions[] = {"Question1", "Question2"};`

Answer (score 2):

you may just change your code logic a little bit

```
 String[]question = new String[2];
question[0] = "Question 1"; 
question[2] = "Question 2";      

String[]answer = new String[8];
answer[0] = "Answer 1";
answer[1] = "Answer 2";
answer[2] = "Answer 3";
answer[3] = "Answer 4";
answer[4] = "Answer A";
answer[5] = "Answer B";
answer[6] = "Answer C";
answer[7] = "Answer D";

for (int i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {

    System.out.println(question[i]);

    for (int j = i*4; j<(i+1)*4; j++) {


            System.out.println(answer[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the second loop definition with this

```
for (int j = i*4; j<(i*4+4); j++) {
```

Also, replace the third line with this

```
question[1] = "Question 2";
```

I think this is a typo in the sample code you posted.